# Adding a variable to xpath?

Tags: ruby

I have an object with XPath, and I want to change `1234` to some variable:

```
:xpath => "//*[@id='blablabla-1234']/div/"
```

Solutions like `:xpath => "//*[@id='blablabla-#{variable}']/div/"` don't work because I have an error like:

```
unable to locate element, using {:tag_name=>"div", :xpath=>"//*[@id='blablabla-']/div/
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Odd, it works fine for me. Are you sure that `variable` is correctly set?

Comment: Your solution works here: `variable = "foo"; p "//*[@id='blablabla-#{variable}']/div/"`. Could you post a more complete snipped of the offending code? If `variable` is nil, the behaviour observed is normal (`nil.to_s` is "")

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [this](https://rubygems.org/gems/jini) library to build xpaths, it is easier to use

```
require 'jini'
xpath = Jini
  .new
  .add_node('parent') # addition a path node
  .add_node('child') # addition a path node 
  .add_attr('key', 'value') # addition an attribute
  .remove_node('child') # removes node
  .to_s # convert it to a string
puts(xpath) # -> xpath: /parent[@key="value"]
```